# The use of "that" in passive voice structure

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

For a publishing writing, I need to use "*that*" in a sentence which structured of **passive voice**. Is the following correct passive voice sentence  ?

*The profiles of **the velocity that is applied** at the inlet of the channel are provided in Figure 1.*

Where, velocity is defined by an equation in the same section.

Please note that: my question about the bold text part in the sentence, and not about "profiles ... are provided" part.

Comment: Thank you for your edits and clarification. Yes, that is a passive sentence using _that_ correctly. You could also use _which_ as part of the relative clause. No commas, as it is restrictive.

Comment: That said...I wonder about "_in_ the inlet of the channel ".  Maybe _to_?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your patient. Sorry, it must be "at the inlet" or "on the inlet".

Comment: "At" is fine...